# Loading issue with IOS 9 with cordova 4.2

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ember.js

I have a problem with cordova 4.2 while using Xcode 7.0.1,when I run my application on IOS9 ,loading JS files taking around 25 seconds which is very bad comparing to android.
I tried to detect the problem by putting flag ,the loading is stuck with getting the handlebars (Since I am using Ember js).
I tried to minify the hbs with no improving.

```
function onDeviceReady() { 
Helpers.getScript('app/app.js');
Helpers.getScript('app/helpers.js');
Helpers.getScript('app/init.js');
Helpers.getScript('app/router.js');
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the HTML element where you list/load your JS files?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am loading those files on deviceReady() as below:
function onDeviceReady()
{ 
            Helpers.getScript('app/app.js');
            Helpers.getScript('app/helpers.js');
     Helpers.getScript('app/init.js');
     Helpers.getScript('app/router.js');
}

Comment: NO. Please put the code in the original post. I cannot read it.

Comment: Hmmm?! I'm confused. In those scripts, is there live code that fires when you call it, or is it just a bunch of functions?

Comment: Here i am loading all templates,routes,controllers,components using AJAX call.

Comment: So you are loading file from those JS scripts? or functions? If you are loading the files, where are they stored? On the device, on a webserver?

Comment: Yes ,I am loading those files on the device .

Answer (score 0):

Okay. If all you are doing is loading files, then there is no need to delay loading those files. The only time you want to delay loading a file ***is*** if you have some active code in those files.

To be clear, there are some libraries that load and become active as soon as they are loaded. Those libraries would set variables or access the system in some way. These types of libraries need to be loaded AFTER the `deviceready` event. Otherwise, you are free to load libraries as soon as you can, and even before the `deviceready` event.

On your App, I cannot say why it is delaying to start. You say 20+ seconds, and I can only think it might be the delayed library loading.

NOTE: not all apps are built the same. This means that on Android, there are libraries that come with the system, and there are libraries that Cordova adds. It might, (might be) that you are loading a larger APP on an iOS system, and that might be the delay.

In any case, let me know what you have tries, and what worked and what did not.

Comment: Thanks man for the reply.actually I tried to detect the problem in some handlebars(.hb files) and comment them.Then  I tried to run the app again it took 4 seconds. the size of those files are big but it should take 2 seconds or 1 second pre .hbs comparing to others that took 20 milliseconds.